# For custom DNS records in email, will having 2 MX with same priority cause issues?

Tags: web-hosting, mx-record, gmail, crm, dreamhost

I want to connect a CRM (Keela) email system to a company's (OJ) domain. That way, when they send emails from the CRM, it appears as "@oj.com". The CRM instructs you to go the hosting service and add custom DNS records (CNAME and MX).

OJ uses Dreamhost hosting service. The CRM uses Sendgrid for emails. The CRM instructs to add custom MX which looks like this:

[Screenshot of MX record screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yU6x.png)

As you can see in the screenshot, OJ currently uses Gmail.

So here's my question; will adding the new MX (in red box) break their Gmail? Since both Sendgrid MX and Gmail MX are on the same priority (10), won't that cause issues with receiving email?

I don't want their Gmail to be effected. All emails should continue going to their Gmail inbox. But when they use the CRM to send email, it should have their domain (@oj.com) rather than the CRM's domain (@keela-account.com).

I'm totally new to this. I want to be very careful before I add this MX otherwise I risk breaking their email system.

Answer (score 3):

The MX records are for reveiving mail. The CRM most likely only sends messages. Do not add the MX record. Instead, focus on configuring SPF+DKIM+DMARC to support this new use case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will break their Gmail, as other mail servers will start to round-robin between the 2 MX hosts with priority 10. So some of the email will hit Gmail and some of it will hit Sendgrid. This is probably not what you want.

I'm speculating that what you do actually want is maybe some of the email, depending on sender and/or recipient, to be cloned and/or forwarded onto Sendgrid by Gmail, in which case, you should configure rules in their Gmail setup to do that.